# what libraries do i need to run this keygenerator class

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption

Which libraries do I need to import for this class?

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kgen.init(128);
```

If you would prefer not to give me the answer that I seek, then please tell me how can I find out about these libraries. By the way, I use Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[First google result for KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where you got it from, etc., but Eclipse gives you hints based on what it can determine from your code and what code is it's libraries.

IIRC: Where you see the yellow exclamation double clicking that will give you a list based on what it thinks you meant (I find that it is right about 90% of the time) or (AFM) press F1 when the caret is on that line.